# Proof verification: This subset of the domain of a function is closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

I know that there is a theorem stating that 
if a function $f$ is continuous from $X$ to $Y$, with $X,Y$ topological spaces, then the preimage of a subset $V$ of $Y$ is closed in $X$ whenever $V$ is closed in $Y$.
If I am given that $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous with Euclidean metrics, and I want to show that for any $c\in\mathbb{R}, $ $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: f(x,y,z)=c\}$ is closed for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$, can I simply invoke this theorem and the fact that any singleton set $\{c\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$?  If this is the case, this problem seems very simple...too simple.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: In fact, your argument (without any essential modification) shows that for any continuous map of topological spaces $f:X \rightarrow Y$, where the points of $Y$ are closed (i.e., $Y$ is Hausdorff), then the fibers over a point $f^{-1}(y) \subset X$ are closed.